# How to DRY up GitHub Actions by listing multiple OS's for the same job?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have this GitHub Actions workflow working:

```
name: Test Bootstrap

on: push

jobs:
  bootstrap-on-mac:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Bootstrap
        run: ./bootstrap.sh

  bootstrap-on-ubuntu:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Bootstrap
        run: ./bootstrap.sh
```

But is there a way to combine the jobs into a single job that gets executed on multiple operating systems?

So something like this?:

```
name: Test Bootstrap

on: push

jobs:
  bootstrap-on-mac:
    runs-on:
      - macos-latest
      - ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Bootstrap
        run: ./bootstrap.sh
```

I couldn't get the above working because I think GitHub interprets it as requiring an OS that's labelled `macos-latest, ubuntu-latest`, which doesn't exist.

I tried to use the `matrix` strategy, but I kept on getting errors and none of the example matrices are 1 dimensional.  All of the examples are 2 dimensions or higher.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered here: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/39131#discussioncomment-4146138

Essentially, the matrix feature works and can implemented like so:

```
jobs:
  bootstrap:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os:
          - macos-latest
          - ubuntu-latest
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
      - ...
```